# What should I do if I’m bisexual?

Tags: halal-haram, homosexuality, sexuality

Salam,

I understand that homosexuality is forbidden in Islam, but I don’t have a choice. I’m a bisexual man and I can’t act like I’m not. This is something that I’ve hated and always tried to block out of my life, due to Islam, but I can’t act like it’s not there. I didn’t choose to be Bi, but I am. What should I do? I still pray and try to be the best Muslim I can be, but I don’t know what to do about my homosexuality. Is it ok for me to practice Islam and be Bi, is there something I should do, or is it totally acceptable and I’m worrying over nothing?
Please, help me out and let me know.

Comment: "What should I do..." questions are a bad fit for our site. As this site is not meant fir counseling nor a support group.

Answer (score 1):

وعليکم السلام ورحمة الله وبرکاته

The attraction and desire in of itself is not sinful, whether it is towards someone of the same gender or opposite.

What is sinful are the acts that occur, which are looking with desire, touching, sexual relations etc.

So long as you avoid these sins, whether it is towards someone of the same gender or opposite gender, then you are rewarded for avoiding them.

Merely having an inclination or desire to a person, of any gender, does not affect your Islām.

May Allāh make it easy for yourself and ourselves to avoid falling into the temptations of our nafs.

Comment: So if I were to fantasize about the same gender, without any type of real sexual relationship with one, then it’s ok? I have these thoughts and fantasies all the time, but it’s very hard to stop them.

Comment: @ColinErica It's best not to fantasize (and this is coming from someone who's bisexual). A great way to ward off such thoughts would be to distract your mind, perhaps read some Qur'an or listen to some Islamic lectures/Qur'an. Basically, tell yourself to think about Allah.